# CollectionViewCell press effect

Tags: ios, ipad, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to give press effect for `collectionViewCell` on `didSelectItem`. On click I would like to add some color and after some delay I would like to revert the color. While trying the code below, press effect is added only after some delay. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as ..cell

    // Change bg color for foreground layer
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCell(timer:)) , userInfo: ["cell":cell,"collectionview":collectionView], repeats: false)
    }
    // Some calculations
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing right pls mention.

Comment: where u struck.

Comment: if i dont do any operations it gives expected results. When i do any calculations below timer code  then color changes triggerd only after few delaty

Answer (score 0):

`.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as ..cell` should usually be called in the main thread, you might see weird behavior if you are doing it from your utility queue

I suggest also to not use DispatchQueues and handle animation timing by yourself, there's already a nice function that does exactly what you want. This would be my suggestion:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as ..cell
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.4, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }, completion: { _ in
        // here the animation is done
    })
}
```

### Update with a nicer solution

Anyway, i think a nicer approach than handling the animation in the `didSelectItemAt` function of your `UICollectionViewDelegate` would be overriding the `isSelected` property of the cell.

In this example, I animate the backgroundColor whenever the selection state of the UICollectionViewCell changes - red when selected, green otherwise. Just replace that with whatever style you desire.

```
class YourCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet(newValue) {    
            let newColor = isSelected ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.4, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = newColor
            }, completion: { _ in
                // here the animation is done - nothing to do here probably
            })
        }
    }

}
```